# microservices: async api feedback

Tags: microservices, event-driven

I don't quite to figure out how to get feedback response from an async api.

I mean, an async service responds with any type of response like: "ok, received."

I know that there are several ways to poll about any operation status (long poll, server-sent events, websockets...).

For me, this way to get feedback is at the same time a way to overloading service.

I mean, I'm building an async service in order to optimize operations, but at the same time, I need to handle a lot of "check state" requests.

By other hand, which sentences could I do to my boss when he's requesting me about "what about is async operation fails"? How client is feedback then?

Comment: Call backs, real time services etc. There's lots of ways around this if you just do a bit of research.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using Callback mechanism (fire and forget ) .

```
Steps :
1-  req:Call async api  
     resp: ok received , callback url with unique request id .
2-  Processing started for request in async api and once it will finished it will send callback to requestor with status of req.
3- Parallel you can check the status of your request (you need to develop another api which will return status of your request by id) 

Total Api needed:
  1- Client.
  2- Asysnc processor api with callback functionality.
  3- Get request status  api which will return the status of request.
```

Comment: But SPA are not able no receive any callback since are running in a browser...

Comment: then you should show status  somewhere in the browser or any screen , where requestor can check the status of request.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common concern & theory only would be a foundation to a good answer!

`Asynchronous` calls are meant to be for events or calls which `mostly doesn't` require a realtime feedback or attention. Hence, their processing should (or can be done) in queues, sequentially or with time.

`Client feedback point`

We can certainly revert with an accept message (`with or without reponse body)` once the request is received and sent for processing. In your case, you'd definitely require another endpoint/service/etc depending on design to check for status since that is the only way you would we requesting a `resource` in API world (REST or SOAP)!

`What if async operation fails`

You'll definitely have to choose a better async supporter ( For e.g. You may choose which is more consistent and `fault taulerant` , `Kafka (i'll prefer this), RabbitMQ` , some other MQ etc) Since most of these systems are tested well with higher throughputs and you may read and compare their architectures!

**So ultimately it depends on how you design & choose what is best needed for your systems!**