# How can I response status code with asynchronous Request/Response?

Tags: microservices, saga, event-driven

Hello I'm trying to make a toy project and made SignUp API with Saga Orchestrator and kafka.
And I need to respond JWT Token when success to client.
When I create user in PENDING state, I need to respond to request and send kafka message to other service.
When other service success, user service update their state to CREATED.
But I don't know how to respond http status code and response body to client.
How can I send response to client?

Follow is my flow chart
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where your request is being processed in `Async` manner (like Kafka, RabbitMQ etc), an ideal solution would be to use `HTTP 200 Accepted` or `HTTP 204 No Content` response.

These status code indicates that your request was valid and has been taken up, however, you don't certainly need to send a response body in return !

At the most, it would be sufficient if you'd return a response with a JSON or XML or text message saying something like this ...

```
Http 200/204

{

"success": "your request is processing..."

}
```

You may read about response codes here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71415919/microservices-async-api-feedback/72667350#72667350` Similar concerns in this article too !